# dovecot + memcached, how to?

Tags: dovecot, memcached, memcache

Does anyone know how to utilize **memcached** with **dovecot** (in order to reduce number of MySQL queries)?
There is only very basic documentation regarding dovecot's Dictionary:

```
memcached:param=value:param2=value2:...

Supported parameters are:

host: Memcached server host (default: 127.0.0.1)
port: Memcached server port (default: 11211)
prefix: Prefix to add to all keys (default: empty)
timeout_msecs: Abort lookups after specified number of milliseconds (default: 30000)
```

and not a single word or configuration example how to utilize this for existing MySQL POP3 and IMAP authentication. There are other lookups as well that may benefit from memecached as well (for example resolving addresses to paths etc. ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer:

uri = memcached:host=127.0.0.1:port=11211

[Found the hint on a Thread from Dovecot on 2013](https://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2013-December/094222.html)

Comment: @milosdakonovic if you agree I would be happy if you could accept my answer